# Accessing a value from a dropdown menu in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a dropdown menu that starts default with no value, so the element looks like this:

```
<div class="jss213">
  <div class="jss214 jss217 jss243 jss228" aria-pressed="false" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">Basketball
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value>
  <svg class="jss86 jss219" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

But when the value is selected, this is how the element looks, with the input value = "Basketball":

```
<div class="jss213">
  <div class="jss214 jss217 jss243 jss228" aria-pressed="false" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">Basketball
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="Basketball">
  <svg class="jss86 jss219" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

I also get the same output when logging the element with this:

```
console.log(root.getElementsByClassName("jss213"))
```

I'm trying to access the "value" field using this:

```
var serviceName = root.getElementsByClassName("jss213").value
```

This, however, causes the page to crash with the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".
Is there a way to check for this value without causing an undefined error? Or a way to make sure that the dropdown has properly selected a value before selecting it?

Comment: JS arrays are 0 indexed, are you looking for the first result? (That would be `[0]` rather than `[1]`)

Comment: Yes. There is a dropdown on the left and right side of this dropdown, with the [0] index matching the first one, so this it to access the second one. But I'll just remove it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: divs don't have a `.value` property.  Also `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: theres something else going on if `getElementsByClassName` is giving you `undefined`. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your analysis of the problem is totally off. _“which makes sense because since a value hasn't been selected yet when first navigating to the page, the value is undefined”_ - then attempting to _read_ that value would _get_ you `undefined`, and not an error.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
var serviceName = root.querySelector(".jss213 input")?.value
```

the ? checks if the element with the class jss213 has an input field with a possible value
it either returns "" or the value "basketball" or whatever the value is set to

Comment: not sure if this is what you want to accomplish, your example is a bit abstruse.

Comment: I think this is the solution I was looking for. Looks like querySelector allows you to check if a value exists without explicitly trying to access it in variable form.

Comment: @knxwledge its more that the ? does that. querySelector just makes it easier, i could have used getEleByClassname()[0].getEleByClassname()[0]?.value. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-question-mark-works-in-javascript/ i use it for Optional Chaining